# Compares 2 tables and deletes rows if 2 columns same rows and the remaining one is different in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, subquery, sql-delete

The data in table A has 1 million rows and columns A, B, C, D, E
And table B has 5000 rows and columns A, B, C, D, E, and F.

I'm going to delete the data from table A

I would like to delete the rows if there is a A and B columns same value and C column values in the table A but not in the table B.

The columns A, B, and C of the A table are indexed.
For table B, if you group with columns A, B, and C, the eigenvalues are less than 100 rows.

Table A

````
|A|B|C|
|-|-|-|
|A|A|A|
|A|A|B ```Delete```|
|A|A|B ```Delete```|
|A|B|A|
|A|B|C|
|A|C|A|
|A|C|B|
|A|C|C ```Delete```|
|B|A|A|
|B|B|A|
|B|B|B|
|B|B|C|
|B|C|A|
|B|C|B|
|B|C|C|
|C|A|A|
|C|A|B|
|C|A|C|
|C|B|B|
|C|B|C|
|C|C|A|
|C|C|B|
|C|C|B|
|C|C|C|
|C|C|C|
|C|C|C|
|C|C|C|
|C|C|C|
|C|C|C|
````

Table B

```
|A|B|C|
|-|-|-|
|A|A|A|
|A|A|C|
|A|B|A|
|A|B|C|
|A|C|A|
|A|C|B|
```

Comment: Why are some rows marked as delete - for a,a,b cola and colb are the same but colc does exist in table B in 4 rows in 2 columns, and why a,c,c deleted given cola and colb are not the same?

Comment: The targets that have the same A and B columns in Table A and Table B are the candidate groups to be deleted from Table A. = A.A=B.A AND A.B=B.B
And if the candidate A&B&C column value is not found in the B table, delete the row.

Comment: Still not with you - what does Table A. = A.A=B.A AND A.B=B.B mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want to remove rows from `tablea` whose `(a, b)` tuple exists in `tableb` *but* whose `(a, b, c)` tuple does not exist.

If so, I would recommend `exists` and `not exists`:

```
delete from tablea ta
where exists (select 1 from tableb tb where ta.a = tb.a and ta.b = tb.b)
    and not exists (select 1 from tableb tb where ta.a = tb.a and ta.b = tb.b and ta.c = tb.c)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)
My head hurts so much, this helped!